# htaccess and file-structure for web project

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, web, project

I have this structure in my web-project:

```
domain.com

    -index.php

    frontend

        .htaccess
        -index.php
        -home.php
        -404.php
        -new_site.php

        account

            -index.php
            -new_site.php

    backend

        -backendfiles.php
        -etc..
```

My files,

domain.com/index.php :

```
include ( 'frontend/index.php' );
```

domain.com/frontend/.htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?values=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

domain.com/frontend/index.php :

```
$str = $_GET[ 'values' ];
$str = str_replace( '../', '', $str );

$vars = explode( '/', $str );
$path = '';
foreach( $vars as $var ) {
    $p = strpos( $var, ':' );
    if( $p == 0  ) {
        $path .= $var . '/';
        continue;
    }
    $_GET[ sub_str( $var, 0, $p ) ] = sub_str( $var, $p + 1 );
}

if( $path ) {

     // File
     $file = $path . '.php';
     if( file_exists( $file ) ) {
         include( $file );
         exit;
     }

     // Direction
     $file = $path . '/index.php';
     if( file_exists( $file ) ) {
         include( $file );
         exit;
     }

     // Page not found
     // include( '404.php' );

}

// Default Page
include( 'home.php' );
```

What i tried...

When i call:

```
domain.com
```

=> load content from domain.com/frontend/home.php => works

When i call:

```
domain.com/new_site
```

=> load content from domain.com/frontend/new_site.php => does not work

When i call:

```
domain.com/account
```

=> load content from domain.com/frontend/account/index.php => does not work

When i call:

```
domain.com/account/new_site
```

=> load content from domain.com/frontend/account/new_site.php => does not work

Anybody could help me with this?

Is my structure good or should i change it?

Greetings and thanks!

Comment: "does not work" - does it produce any errors?

Comment: that´s what i exactly get: Not Found

The requested URL /account was not found on this server.

Comment: have you try to debug your index.php? try to echo (not include) and you will find where is the problem.

Comment: what do you mean by 'echo' ? could you explain with code?

Comment: sorry but if you dont' know how to echo something in PHP you should start from reading manual not from writing code.

Comment: i mean, what code fragment exactly i should echo...and why?

Comment: you mean my domain.com/frontend/index.php ?

Comment: excuse me, but you still here? because i dont know what you exactly want violator667 .